# Photo thumbnails in dynamic grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application where I need to display photo thumbnails. There are usually one photo attached to a specific post, but sometimes there are two, three or four, but rarely any more than that.

If a post contains one photo I would like to display a big thumbnail. If it contains two photos I would like to display two smaller side by side. For three photos I would like the first to be big and the last two to be displayed below the first one, and if there are four photos I'd like to have them all displayed the same size in a 2x2 grid. If there are more than four I'd like a small ellipsis button that is displayed at the bottom with the full width of the thumbnail grids, but a small height.

So something like this:

```
1 photo              2 photos             3 photos

|-----------|        |-----------|        |-----------|
|           |        |  T  |  T  |        |           |
|     T     |        |-----------|        |     T     |
|           |                             |           |
|-----------|                             |-----------|
                                          |  T  |  T  |
                                          |-----------|

4 photos             5 photos

|-----------|        |-----------|
|  T  |  T  |        |  T  |  T  |
|-----------|        |-----------|
|  T  |  T  |        |  T  |  T  |
|-----------|        |-----------|
                     |    ...    |
                     |-----------|
```

How is this possible without creating 5 different grids and switching their visibility depending on the number of photos? I'm also using MVVM and therefore databinding, which could complicate that matter.

Comment: Your question is essentially a set of _requirements_.  Any code to show?  [ask]

Comment: @MickyD No, because I don't know where to start. I've googled a lot about dynamic grids, but I can't seem to find any scenarios that somewhat cover my requirements.

Comment: MD: _"Your question is essentially a **set of requirements**"_;  GTH: _"**No**, because I don't know where to start... I can't seem to find any scenarios that somewhat cover **my requirements**"_  - oh dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use different DataTemplates and a custom template selector that decides which template to use based on the number of images available in a given model. You would still need to declare the grids separately, but you wouldn't trigger the visibility of all grids since the template selector would only return the template applicable to the corresponding number of images.

EDIT: Adding example and link to source

The following is an example from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

It shows how a custom `DataTemplateSelector` can be used to return a suitable template based on the given parameters in `SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)`.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>

  <!--Create two DataTemplate objects to be 
  selected by the DataTemplateSelector.-->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="numberTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <Rectangle Stroke="Black" />
      <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="18"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="largeNumberTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <Ellipse Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="24" 
                 Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <local:NumderDataTemplateSelector x:Key="numberTemplateSelector"/>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>

  <!--Bind the content of the Label to the selected item 
  in the ComboBox.-->
  <Label  Foreground="Black"
          Content="{Binding ElementName=numberList, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"
          ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource numberTemplateSelector}">
  </Label>

  <ComboBox Name="numberList">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>5</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>6</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">7</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>9</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>

</StackPanel>
```

The TemplateSelector in C#:

```
public class NumderDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string numberStr = item as string;

        if (numberStr != null)
        {
            int num;
            Window win = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            try
            {
                num = Convert.ToInt32(numberStr);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Select one of the DataTemplate objects, based on the 
            // value of the selected item in the ComboBox.
            if (num < 5)
            {
                return win.FindResource("numberTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return win.FindResource("largeNumberTemplate") as DataTemplate;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I create a selector like that? Any links or examples available, as I've never done that before.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) has a small example for the `ContentTemplateSelector` property of a `ContentControl`. A `TemplateSelector` for a grid should work basically the same way.

Comment: If providing links only is an issue, feel free to write an answer and provide the links as sources instead.

Comment: The "This" in my previous comment is a link to an example on MSDN. Okay, maybe that wasn't so obvious. [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example of `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: @ThomasEggemann I did see that and appreciate it, and it certainly looks like something I can use :) The previous comment was more a comment to MickyD. However, link-only-posts on SO are not encouraged, though, so a proper example with links at the bottom would probably be more helpful to future users in case Microsoft changes their documentation structure and the link doesn't work any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a binding approach, as I imagine you'd need to write your own control to properly get this in a way where you're not relying on multiple grids being shown / hidden.

I'd recommend going with a custom control (maybe a derivative of ItemsPresenter), and I've thrown together this basic LinqPad snippet:

```
void Main()
{
    var window = new Window();
    var photos = new[] { 
        "http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg",
        "http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg",
        "https://media2.giphy.com/media/yAqdjThdDEMF2/200_s.gif",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNycdfFEgBc/maxresdefault.jpg",
        "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg"
        };
    var grid = BuildGrid(photos);
    window.Content = grid;
    window.Show();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

Tuple<int, int, int, int> GetItemPosition(int pos, int count)
{
    if (count == 1)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(0, 2, 0, 4);
    }

    if (count == 2)
    {
        if (pos == 1) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (pos == 2) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    if (count == 3)
    {
        if (pos == 1) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 0, 2);
        if (pos == 2) return Tuple.Create(1, 0, 0, 0);
        if (pos == 3) return Tuple.Create(1, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    if (count == 4)
    {
        if (pos == 1) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (pos == 2) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 1, 0);
        if (pos == 3) return Tuple.Create(1, 0, 0, 0);
        if (pos == 4) return Tuple.Create(1, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    if (count == 5)
    {
        if (pos == 1) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (pos == 2) return Tuple.Create(0, 0, 1, 0);
        if (pos == 3) return Tuple.Create(1, 0, 0, 0);
        if (pos == 4) return Tuple.Create(1, 0, 1, 0);
        if (pos == 5) return Tuple.Create(3, 0, 0,2);
    }

    return null;
}

Grid BuildGrid(string[] photos)
{
    var grid = new Grid();
    grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    var fillLength = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

    for (var col = 0; col < 2; col++)
    {
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = fillLength });
    }

    for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = fillLength });
    }

    for (var idx = 0; idx < photos.Length; idx++)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        var bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri( photos[idx], UriKind.Absolute);
        bi.EndInit();
        img.Source = bi;
        img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        var pos = GetItemPosition(idx + 1, photos.Length);
        pos.Dump();
        if (pos == null) continue;

        img.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, pos.Item1);
        img.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, pos.Item2 == 0 ? 1 : pos.Item2);
        img.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, pos.Item3);
        img.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, pos.Item4 == 0 ? 1 : pos.Item4);

        grid.Children.Add(img);
    }
    return grid;
}
```

It's by no means perfect, but it shows the rough basics of how you could do this.

The behaviour of showing an ellipse and cutting off after 5 items also isn't implemented, but shouldn't be too difficult to achieve.